# Unable to fetch all guild members through Discordjs v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to fetch the list of all members in my guild using the syntax as mentioned in the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). But am not receiving any output. Below is the code that I am using.

```js
const { Client, Intents, Guild } = require("discord.js");
require("dotenv").config();
const commandHandler = require("./commands");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const client = new Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_PRESENCES"],
});

client.once("ready", async (data) => {
    console.log("Ready!");
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    const Guilds = client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild);
    console.log(Guilds[0]);
    await Guilds[0].members.fetch().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === "ping") {
        await interaction.reply(client.user + "");
    }
});

client.on("messageCreate", commandHandler);
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN); // Kushagra's bot
```

I am getting the information on Guild instance through the `console.log` on line 13. But do am not getting any output for line 15.
However, I noticed that I was getting some output if I add options to `fetch()` command on line 14. I received some output when I added `{query: 'random text'}`.

Just wanted to understand why I am unable to get a list of all members.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found that I had missed out on the Intent.
It seems that in order to fetch members you need to add an intent `GUILD_MEMBERS` while creating a client instance.

So replacing the client creation with the one below will work.

```
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MEMBERS"] 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was searching for a fix for hours until I realized I didn't add the intents.